# Use std::remove_if on a std::vector filled with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a little question about the `std::remove_if` function. I have a memory leak somewhere in my program, and I suspect the `erase` function to be broken somehow.

Actually, I have this in my code

```
std::vector<Object*> v; // Just the constructor to show you
v.erase(std::remove_if(begin(v), end(v), [Foo f](Object *o){
    return o->containsFoo(f);
}), end(v));
```

But after some research, is this better than the previous?

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(begin(v), end(v), [Foo f](Object *o){
   if(o->containsFoo(f)) {
     delete o;
     return true; 
   }
   return false;
}), end(v));
```

Or should I use something else?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`

Comment: @T.C. should I use unique_ptr instead of the Type* pointers?

Comment: @T.C.  That's not a comment - that's the answer.  Put it in an answer and I can upvote it, and the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne yes. `std::unique_ptr` will delete the pointer automatically at the end of it's scope like when removde from a container and has no processing or runtime overhead.

Comment: "I have a memory leak _somewhere_ in my program..." - and Valgrind didn't tell you where??  You should demonstrate that you have made _some_ effort to solve your problem!

Comment: @TobySpeight I used valgrind, but it pointed me to the SFML window, without anymore informations. But I figured out what whas wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You really should be using a **smart pointer** rather than bare `Object*` - either

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>
```

or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>
```

whichever is appropriate.  If you use naked C-style pointers, it's much too easy to miss a crucial `delete` (or to `delete` twice).

Notwithstanding, it's pretty easy to see that one approach leaks and the other does not:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    std::vector<int*> v{ new int(1), new int(-1) };

    if (argc < 2) {
        // First version
        v.erase(std::remove_if(begin(v), end(v),
                               [](int *o){
                                   return *o < 0;
                               }),
                end(v));
    } else {
        // Second version
        v.erase(std::remove_if(begin(v), end(v),
                               [](int *o){
                                   if (*o < 0) {
                                       delete o;
                                       return true;
                                   }
                                   return false;
                               }),
                end(v));
    }

    // normal cleanup
    for (int *p: v)
        delete p;

}
```

I run this without an argument (invoking the first version) and then with an argument (invoking the second version).  Look what happens:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra 34191606.cpp -o 34191606
```

---

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./34191606
==16894== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16894==     in use at exit: 72,708 bytes in 2 blocks
==16894==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 72,728 bytes allocated
==16894== 
==16894== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==16894==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16894==    by 0x400881: main (34191606.cpp:6)
==16894== 
==16894== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16894==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==16894==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16894==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16894==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==16894==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16894== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==16894== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./34191606 -
==16895== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16895==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==16895==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 72,728 bytes allocated
==16895== 
==16895== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16895==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16895==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16895==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16895==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==16895==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16895== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==16895== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

Notice that in the first version, you never delete the object whose pointer you removed from the vector, and that's reported as leaked.  In the second version, there's no leaked memory.

Comment: Ty, I switched to the shared_ptr, but I still got some trouble with the algorith. The results are not the same compared to the version without pointers.

Comment: That sounds like a new question; if you can distil that problem down to a [MCVE](/help/mcve), then please [ask it separately](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

The lambda is *better*, but if I were you (and you are not prepared to use `std::unique_ptr` for some reason), I would do:

```
const auto predicate = [Foo f](Object *o){return !o->containsFoo(f);};
const auto new_end = std::partition(begin(v), end(v), predicate);
std::for_each(new_end, end(v), [](Object *o){delete o;});
v.erase(new_end,end(v));
```

In other words:

1. use <del>`remove_if`</del> `partition` to shuffle unwanted pointers to the end
2. use `for_each` to delete all the unwanted objects
3. use `erase` to get rid of the (now invalid) unwanted pointers.

The point is, that deleting pointers while things are being moved around is hairy.

Comment: If you want to go down this route, you need `partition`, not `remove_if`.

Comment: Edited to fix., and to clarify *why*.

Comment: emphasize that he really needs to use smart pointers and you get my upvote

Comment: I think that `[](Object *o){delete o;}` can be spelt `std::default_delete<Object>()` (actually, that's not any shorter, is it?  but it's no longer reinventing a wheel).

Comment: Oooh.  I didn't know about std::default_delete.  That's shiny.  It's no longer inventing a wheel, and it has a *name*.  Also, in real code I probably would have split the foreach lambda over multiple lines.